# Запуск go при помощи systemd

Tags: golang

Хочу развернуть программу на VPS c Ubuntu 16.04.

Если запускать `go run main.go`, то пройдя по http://ip:8000 вижу вывод работающей программы.

Когда же запускаю через `service` файл, нужно указывать прямой путь до бинарника, что-то типа `/usr/bin/go run` `/path/to/program/src/main.go`, но тогда по http://ip:8000 вижу 404, а если это делать при помощи `systemd`, то вывод команды `systemctl status myproject.service` следующий, хотя я экспортировал `GOPATH`:

```
Jul 12 09:00:26 localhost systemd[1]: Started Simple implementation of WebSockets Chat on GoLang.
Jul 12 09:00:26 localhost go[4826]: src/main.go:7:9: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/websocket" in any of:
Jul 12 09:00:26 localhost go[4826]:         /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket (from $GOROOT)
Jul 12 09:00:26 localhost go[4826]:         ($GOPATH not set)
```

Вывод команды `whereis go` следующий:

```
go: /usr/bin/go /usr/lib/go /usr/share/go /usr/share/man/man1/go.1.gz
```

И да, действительно,  в `/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/` нету никакой папки `github.com`

При этом она оказалась в корне:

```
root@localhost:~# ls
etc  go  gocode

root@localhost:~/go/src# ls
github.com
```

Почему работает, когда я запускаю просто `go run`, без указания пути до бинарника ? Как запустить использую полный путь, чтобы работало ?

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Запуская  `go run /path/to/program/src/main.go` по адресу `http://ip:8000` вижу 404.

Что происходит? С чем это может быть связано?

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple implementation of WebSockets Chat on GoLang
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/SGWC
ExecStart=/usr/bin/go run /var/www/SGWC/src/main.go

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: GOPATH не экспортировать нужно, а [записывать в `Environment`-секцию юнита](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html). Было бы хорошо и сам юнит приложить.

Comment: А почему вы просто не скомпилируете программу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментарию @Ainar-G, удалось решить так:

Компиляция программы:

```
$ go build main.go
```

А затем изменение настройки юнит файла:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple implementation of WebSockets Chat on GoLang
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/SGWC
ExecStart=/var/www/SGWC/src/main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

И всё :)

Не стоило поднимать панику.

@Ainar-G, ещё раз. благодарю!